# How does having a final variable in a foreach loop work

Tags: java, foreach, final

Consider this piece of code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(final String s : Arrays.asList("a","b","c")){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't serve a specific purpose but to demonstrate the usage of `final` `foreach-loop` variables.

How does this work ? How can a single variable be `final` yet it is assigned a different value with each loop. Or is this variable declared multiple times in different scopes\stacks ?

Comment: I would think it would. if the compiler doesnt complain that implies that a new memory address is allocated for the string each iteration. So the old variable goes out of scope each iteration.

Comment: @GuyBouallet: It's not really a duplicate.  This question is asking about the loop variable of a for-each loop (rather than an arbitrary variable declared inside the loop body).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the Java Language Specification (JLS), [14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The enhanced for statement has the form:
>
> ```
> EnhancedForStatement:
>     for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement
>
> FormalParameter:
>     VariableModifiers_opt Type VariableDeclaratorId
>
> VariableDeclaratorId:
>     Identifier
>     VariableDeclaratorId []
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of
>   the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     VariableModifiers_opt TargetType Identifier =
>         (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

Thus, the `Identifier` is redeclared on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: That's even worse than what I thought about the `for-each` loop. I guess the old style `for-loop` is more optimized then.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: I'm not sure I see how this is "unoptimized"?

Comment: It requires more stack as much as the loops count, to be able to declare a variable with the same name multiple times. While with the old loop, I can declare the same reference outside the loop and reassign it inside the loop.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: I'm not sure there's any significant difference.  Behaviourally, the same variable would be pushed and popped on every iteration; the stack doesn't grow.

Comment: The only way I can think about, to declare a variable with the same name multiple times, is to use a different scope (not applicable here) or in a different stack (ex: recursion). How can a `for-each` loop declare the same variable multiple times without pushing into the stack ?

Answer (score 2):

It simply means you cannot modify the object reference after it has been set. So in this case, "final" applies only within each iteration. :D

Answer (score 1):

The main idea behind allowing `final` in that context is to let you use the loop variable in an anonymous class. Other than that, `final` does not change the semantic of the loop variable `s`: it goes through the elements of the collection in the same way as usual.

Another effect of using `final` is that you are no longer allowed to assign a new value to `s`. This is generally a bad idea, although [the compiler lets you do it](http://ideone.com/FHmKig).